MediaWiki - Email when Changes Occur to Watchlist Pages - No option in Preferences to turn on
I'm looking to enable the ability to alert users when a page on their Watchlist has a change.
To do this, under User Preferences -> Email Options, there should be an option for "Email me when a page or a file on my watchlist is changed" as well as 2 other settings, however they are missing in my preferences.
According to the Documentation , "Causes you to be automatically sent an email when a pages on your watchlist is edited. May not be available on some large wikis." What constitues "some large wikis" and how can I go about changing this or enabling the option?
I am also open to alternative methods to notify users of changes to their watchlist pages.

There may be a solution on this page that states "Technical details
To enable it on a wiki, $wgEnotifWatchlist is set to true, and it still depends on preference settings. The email-message below is: message with id 'enotif body' (talk) Dear $WATCHINGUSERNAME,"

Under Mediawiki User Preferences -> Email Options, this is what it should look like for the option to "Email me when a page or a file on my watchlist is changed". The other two associated settings are visible at the very bottom of the screen shot.

Instead of configuring from the Email section of preferences (what OP linked to as "Documentation"), try starting with the Watchlist section of preferences instead:

These are the settings to control the behavior of the Watchlist ...
Most of these options are also available on the
Watchlist display itself, but by setting them in your preferences, you
control the default behavior of the Watchlist i.e., it will perform
the same actions every time...

See the various caveats and details about receiving email notices based on settings in Watchlist preferences when there are Watchlist changes AND how to configure the settings in the Watchlist itself, in order to get email notifications.
Only changes for certain pages will trigger notifications, see What you cannot watch.
*Don't worry about what constitutes "some large wikis". That refers to Wikipedia-sized installations of Mediawiki that are MUCH larger than your wiki but not as large as the big English, French, German, etc. wikis.

Thanks for clarifying the "some large wikis" part. Rules that out.

The options you've shown in your screenshot do not appear for me under my email options, so I'll be going to the wiki administrator to get that sorted out. Unsure if that's a setting / option that needs to be enabled. That'll be my first step.

@Barnard87 Definitely start there!  Are email responses enabled in your profile? That's at the top of my screenshot. If not, the ones at the bottom, about the watchlist changes, won't show up.
